# Add/Remove Capabilities for logged in user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need some help dynamically assigning capabilities to users when they log in. Specifically, I need the users to have "list_users" capabilities.

I believe I can use the following code to grant them "list_users", but how do I remove it when they are logged out?

```
// get user ID
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// add the capability to the specific user
$user_id->add_cap("list_users" => true);
```

EDIT: This code above crashes my site

Answer (score 1):

add/remove capability to/from specific user -

```
// get user ID
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//to remove capability from user
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->remove_cap( 'can_email');

//to add capability to user
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'can_email');


//to add capability to list_users
$user = new WP_User( $user_id );
$user->add_cap( 'list_users');
```

Comment: Thank you for this! If I want to remove the capability if they aren't logged in, would this work?
            if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

                $user->remove_cap( 'list_users');

            };

Comment: To lock subscribers and contributors out of the admin:

function wp_prevent_login_redirect(){
  if( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') && ( current_user_can('subscriber') || current_user_can('contributor') ) ){
    wp_redirect(home_url());
    exit;
  }
}
add_action('init','wp_prevent_login_redirect');